# Brussels to London as a third-country national

Tags: customs-and-immigration, europe, london, eu, brussels

I am planning to travel to London from Brussels but I am not an EU citizen. I am here for my holiday and business purposes.

I have researched around for the cheaper ways to go to London (they seem cheaper than travelling by plane??):

1. By bus (around 35 euro) from Brussels to London Victoria.
2. By train (around 120 euro) from Brussels to London St Pancras.

I have a few questions:

1. Are they the correct stations to stop at? Or other better choices?
2. Where is the immigration check point that I should be aware off? Is it in Brussels before I depart or at where I arrive in London?
3. What should I do I am refused entry? Will I be paid for my ticket to return to Brussels?

Comment: (1) It depends on your destination in London; (2) it depends on whether you travel by bus or by train; (3) If you are refused entry you will return to Brussels; you will not be paid for your ticket -- instead, use the money or ticket you were planning to use to return from London to Brussels had you been admitted.  Because there are too many questions here, I'm voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's London Victoria station (not Victory) but for bus, that's the correct one
2. It's likely to be at either the entrance or the exit of the tunnel between England and France.
3. No. It's your responsibility to have proper Visa and documentation.

Comment: Regarding 2, if travelling by train the passport check is at the station in Brussels. Not 100% sure about travelling by bus, but I think it will always be on the French side of the channel.

Answer (score 1):

To extend the answer for question 2:

- If traveling by rail, passport checks (emigration-Schengen side only and immigration) happen prior to boarding in either Brussels (to UK) or at St Pancras (from UK). However there are [supplemental checks on exiting in Britain](http://www.eurostar.com/us-en/travel-info/travel-planning/travel-documents) where your documents will be re-checked.
- If traveling by bus, your bus will likely drive onto a ferry in Calais, France that arrives in Dover, England.  Passport emigration (Schengen side only) and immigration checks happen prior to boarding the ferry.